# C++ windows.h include error on Windows 10

Tags: c++, visual-c++, visual-studio-2013, development-environment

I have upgrade my windows 8.1 to windows 10 and I have this compile error for every class that windows.h header file:

```
Error C2208: '_DISK_' : no members defined using this type.
File: C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\Include\um\winioctl.h
```

Any suggestions?
I work on Windows 10, Visual Studio 2013 Update 5.

Regards.

Comment: Upgrading your machine's OS version cannot cause this error.  That file does not contain the word `_DISK_` anywhere.  Not mentioning the error line number doesn't help either.  Look at the date on the file, it was probably accidentally changed by an out-of-control Edit + Replace.

Comment: The error line number is 3325 of file winioctl.h.

Comment: Line 3325 is a comment.  Clearly your winioctl.h was altered somehow, you'll have to restore it from a good machine.  And do look at the file date as I recommended.

Answer (score 1):

Windows kit file's has not changed and Updating Windows Kit doesn't solve the problem.

Fixed.. I have reinstalled Visual Studio 2013.

Answer (score 0):

Try to update the Windows Software Development Kit:
https://dev.windows.com/en-us/downloads/windows-10-sdk

Comment: I have updated Windows Development Kit but I still have the same error.